# How to check if there is any clause after a keyword in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to update Column B as "Eligible" for those columns which don't have any clauses after the Subject= clause

For an example +TEACHER=A+YR=2020+EXPERIENCE="7 years"+SUBJECT='English'+SUBJECT='FRENCH' there is no clause after Subject so column B which is a separate column should be updated as "Eligible" but for row +TEACHER=A+YR=2020+EXPERIENCE="7 years"+SUBJECT='PhysicalEducation'+SPORTS_TEACHERS='Yes' ,there is a clause after subject which is sports_teachers,so column B should be updated as others

For below values, only first two rows should be updated to "Eligible", remaining rows should be updated as "others"

Column A

```
+TEACHER=A+YR=2020+EXPERIENCE="7 years"+SUBJECT='English'+SUBJECT='FRENCH'                       
+TEACHER=A+YR=2021+EXPERIENCE="6 years"+SUBJECT='Maths'                                          
+TEACHER=A+YR=2020+EXPERIENCE="7 years"+SUBJECT='English'+PRINCIPAL='NO'                         
+TEACHER=A+YR=2020+EXPERIENCE="7 years"+SUBJECT='Physical Education'+SPORTS_TEACHERS='Yes'
```

Comment: So what is your question? Your code doesn't appear complete? What isn't working about it?

Comment: Hi Dale,My question is how to check if there is any clause written after Subject clause.For an example +TEACHER=A+YR=2020+EXPERIENCE="7 years"+SUBJECT='English'+SUBJECT='FRENCH'  there is no clause after Subject so column B which is a separate column should be updated as "Eligible" but for row +TEACHER=A+YR=2020+EXPERIENCE="7 years"+SUBJECT='Physical Education'+SPORTS_TEACHERS='Yes' ,there is a clause after subject which is sports_teachers,so it should be updated as others

Comment: [edit] any improvements into the question.

Comment: Fix your schema and stop cramming things together - make your life simpler, your database faster, your queries easier to write, your data easier to maintain. Go find a string splitting function that preserves order and provides it for use in a query (not string_split). Then you simply compare the max row of all subjects with that of all rows.

Comment: Based on the syntax definition that you omitted, it appears that the presence of a plus-sign (`+`) after the _last_ occurrence of `+SUBJECT='` might suffice to differentiate the rows. Can you have `+FOO="BAR"+BAR='FOO'+SUBJECT='TOP'+COMMENT='DO NOT PUT +SUBJECT=''WRONG'' HERE!'`? Anything else that might complicate things? What did you try? (That seems to be missing from some of your earlier questions.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query to get the string before last '=' and then find out if it is `subject` or something else:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([COLA]), CHARINDEX('=',REVERSE([COLA]))+1,7))
```

and update your COL B:

```
UPDATE table
SET [COLB] = CASE WHEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([COLA]), CHARINDEX('=',REVERSE([COLA]))+1,7)) = 'SUBJECT' THEN 'Eligible' ELSE 'Non Eligible' END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ColA varchar(max), ColB varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
 ('+TEACHER=A+YR=2020+EXPERIENCE="7 years"+SUBJECT=''English''+SUBJECT=''FRENCH'''                  , '')
,('+TEACHER=A+YR=2021+EXPERIENCE="6 years"+SUBJECT=''Maths'''                                       , '')
,('+TEACHER=A+YR=2020+EXPERIENCE="7 years"+SUBJECT=''English''+PRINCIPAL=''NO'''                    , '')
,('+TEACHER=A+YR=2020+EXPERIENCE="7 years"+SUBJECT=''Physical Education''+SPORTS_TEACHERS=''Yes'''  , '')


UPDATE T 
    SET ColB = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('+', REPLACE(RIGHT(ColA, LEN(ColA) - CHARINDEX('Subject', ColA) + 1), '+Subject', '')) > 0 THEN 'Others' ELSE 'Elegible' END
FROM    @Table T

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

1. Look for the Word Subject.
2. Get the String from there to the end.
3. Since you can have more than one Subject, replace all of the words "+Subject" with empty string.
4. If there is any remaining "+" is Others, if not it is Elegible.